# Need help with Ubunti 16.04.4 New install

Tags: sound

New to ubuntu and discord both. Installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 on a i3 NUC. Everytime on booting, I get a Sound Icon which is Muted  ( it comes and goes after some time ) and also  all the while the Audio icon on the command line is OK.. What is the sound icon and why does it go away and an I make it to not be Muted ? Just asking !!